# How to prove the Martingale's property if we have a special stopping time?

Tags: probability, martingales, stopping-times, filtrations

$(X_n)$ is a sequence of $(F_n)$-adapted integrable random variables, where $(F_n)$ is a Filtration and $X_0=0$.

I have to prove that

1)$X_n$ is a martingale with a respect to $F_n$

iff

2)for any finite stopping-time $t$ that takes at most two values, we have $E[X_t]=0$

what i have:

"1) to 2)" we can prove that $X_n$ is uniformly integrable and then use Optional Stopping Theorem to show that $E[X_t]=E[X_0]=0.$

"2) to 1)": we have that $X_n$ is integrable and adapted.

How can i show the Martingale property of $(X_n)$ here, and am i wrong in the first part?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the implication 2) implies 1):

**1.** Try first stopping times taking just one value; say, $t=n$ for a positive integer $n$. (Implicit in 2) is the integrability of each random variable $X_n$.)

**2.** Let $m<n$ be non-negative integers and let $A\in F_m$. Consider the stopping time
$$
t(\omega)=\cases{ m,&$\omega\in A$;\cr n,&$\omega\in A^c$.\cr}
$$

Comment: hi, for first one as you said, we obtain that E[Xn]=0 and therefore Xn is martingale, is that what you mean?

Comment: could you please explain 2. specifically, i can't understand why we define A here

Comment: You get $E[X_0]=0$, which is part of being a martingale (since $X_0=0$).

Comment: Using the stopping time $t$ suggested, from $E[X_t]=0$ you deduce that
$$
0=E[X_m\cdot1_{A^c}]+E[X_n\cdot 1_A]=-E[X_m\cdot1_{A}]+E[X_n\cdot 1_A],
$$
where the second equality uses $E[X_m]=0$. You  have deduced that
$$
E[X_n\cdot 1_A]=E[X_m\cdot1_{A}],
$$
for each event $A\in F_m$.  Refer now to your definition of conditional expectation to see that this implies (indeed it equivalent to) 
$$
E[X_n\mid F_m]=X_m.
$$

Comment: thanks, so we split t in to two disjoint parts, and since A is arbitrary, it follows that $$E[X_n-X_m|F_m]=0$$ a.s.

Comment: and was my idea for implication 1) to 2) right and how can i formalize it correctly?

Comment: Yes, optional stopping, which is always valid for a two-valued stopping time.